# AVD is not working properly. It come up but unable to work on that

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

**while I'm trying to open an AVD it look like this.**

[image]

now what I'm suppose to do.

> This is my AVD Configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Try this...**
Create a AVD with following config.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this
```

device:nexsus(4.0,480*800,hdpi)
    Skin:no skin
    cpu/ABI: ARM(eabi-v7a)

Comment: no its not working it keeps loading and loading. any other suggestion ?